# C++ GetModuleFileName Access Violation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, crash, access-violation

I am trying to get the current executable path into a string by using this code (I have tried several other versions of it too, but none of them really works, I always get a access violation at some point)

```
char *filename = new char[MAX_PATH + 1];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, filename, MAX_PATH);
string exe = filename;
```

This fails with an access violation at the first line for some reason. What am I missing?

Comment: You didn't check if GetModuleFileName returned an error.  Second, post a full example that demonstrates the error.  There is little to no chance a 3 line program will have the problem's you're describing.  Last, why are you dynamically allocating memory?  `char filename[MAX_PATH+1]` is all you need to do.

Comment: Sure it's first line?  Also, what OS version?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is the whole code (it is the only part in main. I made this for testing because it did not work in another project). When debugging and making a step on the first line it takes a few seconds and then a access violation pops up. When I click on "show the disassembly" it displays me a address and ?? behind it

Comment: It's Windows 7 64 Bit

Comment: @MartinJames: It's first line. When adding a Messagebox after that, it doesn't display the box but crashed before. Also debugger single step crashes when I execute that line.

Comment: @user3258423 - If the problem is the first line, then why did you state that the problem is GetModuleFileName?  The first line is a call to `new`.

Comment: Because someone might have a working version of a GetModuleFileName returning a string. I am not trying to get this code working, I am trying to find a solution that works (even if it's totally different to what I now have).

Comment: The GetModuleFileName works with `TCHAR`s.  So your usage of `string` (assuming it's `std::string`) is wrong.  If the app is a UNICODE app, this code won't work, and it won't even compile.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: It does compile. But it crashes at runtime. If you have a working version: share with me (when using tchar it crashed at third line when converting tchar to string)

Comment: @user3258423 - It compiles because you're using the (now outdated) MBCS build.  This code will *not* compile if you are targeting a UNICODE application.  So again, usage of `std::string` for such a function is not correct.  See my answer for a correct example, complete with the error check that you still aren't doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version does the error check, and also respects that `GetModuleFileName` works with `TCHAR's` (the second parameter is an `LPTSTR`, which is a pointer to a `TCHAR`).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> TCharString;

int main()
{
   TCHAR filename[MAX_PATH + 1];
   if ( GetModuleFileName(NULL, filename, MAX_PATH) != 0 )
   {
      TCharString strExe = filename;
   }
}
```

Note that since `GetModuleFileName` works with `TCHAR`, it is not correct to blindly use `std::string` as the string type.  Instead, create a string type based on `TCHAR`.

Second, the error check is done to ensure that we do not assign an invalid string to the string object.

Comment: Access Violation at this line TCharString strExe = filename;

Comment: filename is set correctly according to the debugger, but when strExe is set, the access violation occurs

Comment: @user3258423 - Then again, why do you think the issue is with `GetModuleFileName`?  Why not try a very simple C++ program that just does a simple string assignment?  If it doesn't work, then the issue is with your library, compiler, etc., not with `GetModuleFileName`.

Comment: This is what the debugger says me about the 2 variables: strExe "Â\x14" std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >

+  filename 0x002df744 "C:\\Users\\Gonzalez\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\TestApp\\Release\\TestApp.exe" char[261]

I am using VS 2013 (but the project has been created with 2010 and converted.

Comment: The problem only occurs with this! It's a application that assigns other variables too, and only at this variable it crashes

Comment: @user3258423 If the program crashed, then no assignment was done.  So showing the debugger for an assignment that crashed doesn't help.  Second, I'm using VS 2013, and having no issue whatsoever.

Comment: When I do this `TCharString strExe = "Hello";` it works, but when assigning filename it crashes

Comment: I have changed the option multithreaded-dll to multithreaded in C/C++. Does that affect this?

Comment: When using multithreaded-dll it works. But then I can't execute it on other PC's because of a DLL missing...

Comment: @user3258423 - Then install the runtime on the other PC's.  That is all documented by Microsoft.

Comment: That does not really solve my problem being unable to assign the variable by using Multithreaded Runtime

Comment: @user3258423 - Then you have an issue with your compiler setup.  It has nothing to do with the code.  You could debug into the assignment and see exactly why the crash occurs, and then take it from there.  Otherwise, the code as written above in my answer *is* the correct way to use strings and `GetModuleFileName`.  You could also do a deeper inspection of your `filename` that's returned.  Use the `memory window` in the debugger to ensure there are no invalid characters or invisible control characters in the string.

Comment: My `filename` is terminated with '\0' and then filled up with 'Ì'

Comment: @user3258423 Then debug into the assignment function and identify what causes the crash.  Since your problem is unique to you, then you should be getting proactive in identifying why it crashes, and not just say "it crashes".  I tried with both multithread and multithread-dll options -- the code works flawlessly for VS 2013.

Comment: The Problem is with what is assigned, but I can't identify it really: when I do this `TCHAR filename[MAX_PATH + 1] = "c:\\Users\\Gonzalez\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Projekt1\\Debug\\Projekt1.exe\0";
 TCharString strExe = filename;` it also crashes at the second line. I don't understand what is going on here...

Comment: It crashes when there are more than 17 characters that need to be converted. `1234567890123456\0` works, but `12345678901234567\0` crashes.

Comment: @user3258423 - Create a brand new Win32 console project and retry the code I posted.  If it doesn't work, then you should consider either reinstalling VS 2013, or if you haven't done so, get Service Pack 1 for VS 2013.

Comment: I got the problem whenever I initialized a string. I now simply used char => Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

try not using a char pointer . use a char array instead.

Comment: `char filename[MAX_PATH + 1];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, filename, MAX_PATH);
string stringexe = filename;`
Access violation third line

Comment: Did you check the return value for `GetModuleFileName`?  Please read the docs -- never assume that a function will always be successful:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx